# How to find out who the initial dwarves were

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do you find out who the initial 7 dwarves were in Fortress mode? 
Is there a way to get a list of when each dwarves arrived or is it more simple to go in Legends mode?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Dwarf Therapist installed, you can sort by migration wave.  The first seven will be the earliest wave.

Other than that I think Legends mode is your only option.